# Can not show notification on real device using react native firebase

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have an app that using react native and firebase for push notification. 
This is my notification that send to client:

```
   'data' : {
        'title' : ' ' + this.currentUser.email + ' send you a message !',
        'text' : text,
        'senderName' : this.currentUser.email,
        'senderUid': this.currentUser.uid   
    }
```

I use data-only message, and in my code I implement a listener that received the notification:

```
this.onMessageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
                senName = message.data.senderName;
                senUid = message.data.senderUid;

                const showNotif = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                    .setNotificationId('notificationId')
                    .setTitle(message.data.title)
                    .setBody(message.data.text)
                    .android.setChannelId('channel_id_foreground')
                    .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
                firebase.notifications().displayNotification(showNotif)
            })
```

I have tested in simulator, everything work fine. When I run it on real device, it can call `onMessage` but `firebase.notifications().displayNotification(showNotif)` doesn't work as expect. It can not show the notification to the screen.
Anybody know about this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue relative permission on device, did you request grant permission on device ? If user has granted permission, you should check app on android and ios device because sometime ios 9 does not support display a notification while the app is running in foreground.